# Microsoft Team System Equivalent stack

Tags: tfs

I am looking for a free alternative to TFS.  What would be the best alternative stack(source control, bug tracking, project management/planning, wiki, automated builds (ci))? Keeping in mind that it would be nice if they all integrated well.

For example, it would be nice to be able to link  bugs  to source control, and then be able to link to a project plan and then be able to automate building.

I do not have issues with using Microsoft project to manage project planing.

I know i would like to use these....:

- SVN
- TeamCity
- NUnit

But i am struggling to find a good Wiki/Project Planning/Bug tracking, that would integrate well.

Any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bug tracking / project management / planning**
[JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) (not free but $10 for 10 users)
There are various modules to add to this.  I use [GreenHopper](http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/) which is an agile process addon.  YMMV. If you like gant chart planning, there is a [MS Project pluggin](http://www.the-connector.com/index.aspx) (I've not used it)

Also checkout [YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/index.html).  This integrates with TeamCity as a bug tracking tool.  It's quite cheap, but I didn't get on with it in the beta.  YMMV.

There are loads bug tracking systems. This will be where you spend most of your time so I would select one that suits the way you work, rather than one that integrates with your source control (unless you have a very strong requirement for change control/auditability)

**CI / automated build**
All CI servers will integrate with your source control.  I would hazard a guess that all CI servers can be made to work with all source control systems so in this sense they are all integrated.

I used [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for a while which is awsome.  I stopped because I hit the 20 projects limit, and we couldn't afford to upgrade :( I would recommend starting with TeamCity as it is very easy to setup.  Its actually quite easy to change your CI server as long as you keep the actual build in a script.

Also available is [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).  This is free.  There are addons to integrate with SVN + JIRA (in fact the addon scene in Hudson is a real strength).  This means that commits to SVN containing links to issues generates a html link between the hudson build/ jira issue / svn commit making it easier to match code changes to features. Hudson works, but to me it seems like a beta product.  This could change rapidly but I don't have the confidence in it that I had in TeamCity.  However, I shouldn't complain because it's free and I haven't even contributed a bug report :)

The other main CI server is [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) which I've not used.

**Build scripts** 
Nant / msbuild / rake / others.  I use msbuild which with a bit of head scratching can be made to do the business.  I've not used to others.

**Test frameworks**
In .Net land I would guess that NUnit is probably the best supported and most widely known.  There are others, especially those that encourage [BDD](http://flux88.com/blog/the-transition-from-tdd-to-bdd/).

**Wikis**
Not sure what you are after here (I've not used TFS)  There are loads of free wiki engines to choose from.  Full disclosure, I've not used any!

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with.

- SVN (Source Control)
- Team City (Continuous Integration)
- NUnit
- Trac (Project Management/Bug Tracking/Wiki)

Its funny though as a result you now have to install Java (Team City) and python (Trac), to get your free alternative.